# How do I UPDATE two same rows with one with different value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
     ACCT_GRP_CD NUMBER(9),
     MAT_CO_CD VARCHAR2(20),
     ACCT_GRP_NM VARCHAR2(20),
     ACCT_GRP_DESC VARCHAR2(20)
)

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (829, 'MUSA', 'Z HEB', 'Z HEB')
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES (829, 'MUSA', 'Z HEB', 'Z HEB')

SELECT *
FROM T1
```

Returns this output:

```
ACCT_GRP_CD  MAT_CO_CD  ACCT_GRP_NM   ACCT_GRP_DESC
---------------------------------------------------
829           MUSA        Z HEB          Z HEB
829           MUSA        Z HEB          Z HEB
```

Expected result:

```
ACCT_GRP_CD  MAT_CO_CD  ACCT_GRP_NM   ACCT_GRP_DESC
---------------------------------------------------
829           MUSA        HEB            HEB
829           FPUS        HEB            HEB
```

My attempt:

```
UPDATE T1
SET ACCT_GRP_NM = 'HEB', 
WHERE ACCT_GRP_DESC = 'Z HEB' AND 

SET MAT_CO_CD ='FPUS', AND ACCT_GRP_CD ='829'

UPDATE T1
SET ACCT_GRP_NM = 'HEB',
    ACCT_GRP_DESC = 'HEB'
WHERE mat_co_cd IN ('FPUS', 'MUSA')
  AND acct_grp_cd = '829'
  AND ACCT_GRP_DESC = 'Z HEB'
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `merge`:

Before:

```
SQL> select * from t1;

ACCT_GRP_CD MAT_CO_CD            ACCT_GRP_NM          ACCT_GRP_DESC
----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
        829 MUSA                 Z HEB                Z HEB
        829 MUSA                 Z HEB                Z HEB
```

Merge:

```
SQL> merge into t1
  2    using (select a.rowid,
  3             row_number() over (partition by acct_grp_cd order by a.rowid) rn
  4           from t1 a
  5          ) x
  6    on (x.rowid = t1.rowid)
  7    when matched then update set
  8      t1.mat_co_cd = case when x.rn = 1 then 'MUSA'
  9                          when x.rn = 2 then 'FPUS'
 10                     end,
 11      t1.acct_grp_nm = 'HEB',
 12      t1.acct_grp_desc = 'HEB';

2 rows merged.
```

After:

```
SQL> select * from t1;

ACCT_GRP_CD MAT_CO_CD            ACCT_GRP_NM          ACCT_GRP_DESC
----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
        829 MUSA                 HEB                  HEB
        829 FPUS                 HEB                  HEB

SQL>
```